# About Form , Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a HTML form with ID hello

and i have ajax like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#hello").submit(function(){

        var $form = $(this);
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();


        request = $.ajax({
            url: "/blog/ajaxphp/registration_check.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {formData:serializedData},
            datetype: "JSON"
        });
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log("hellosss");
            if(jQuery.parseJSON(response).success==undefined){
                $form.unbind('submit').submit();
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        });
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("error");
        });

     return false;

    });
});
```

But Submit button is not working . i mean it is working if i pressit two times ..

It logs this

Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function  in this line  $form.unbind('submit').submit();

Question :

1. How do i make form enable submit when `jQuery.parseJSON(response).success==undefined` is true otherwise disable form to submit .
2. How do i disable ajax button while ajax process is being performed.

Comment: You are returning `false` immediately after submitting, which stops the rest of your code from being executed. Remove that line and you should at least see some logging.

Comment: The `return` statement ... wait for it .... **returns**, thus ending the function execution

Comment: @InternetJones Yeah thanks but when i put return false at end i need to press submit for 2 times anyreason why?? and how it can be prevented ?

Comment: There is no real reason here to `return` anything as your `submit` doesn't depend on any response, plus it's an asynchronous call so returning anything is impossible.

Comment: @InternetJones I just want the form to enable if jQuery.parseJSON(response).success==undefined is true otherwise i want people to submit form like a normal .. i modified the question check it out

Comment: So you want the submit button to be enabled if your Ajax response is successful? In that case take it out of the `submit()` function, as that code will only trigger once a submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#hello").submit(function(){
    return false;  <-- You are exiting the function right away
    //nothing runs here
```

Use evt.preventDefault();

```
$("#hello").submit(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
```

or if you really want to use return, but it at the BOTTOM.

Also the `return false` in an asynchronous Ajax call does nothing. It is impossible to return anything from an asynchronous call.

EDIT

and you have a typo

```
if(jQuery.parseJSON(response).sucess==undefined){  <-- that is not how you spell `success`
```

Double Edit, see if breaking it up into two parts work.

```
$form.unbind('submit');
$form.submit();
```

Comment: ok I used at bottom ...but still i need to press submit button two times??? is there any problem with me ?? or that is normal ?

Comment: Does `$form.unbind('submit')[0].submit();` make a difference. And note the typo in your code.

Comment: Not working from double edit....Still need to press two times...console.log not loggin anything anyway :(